# How to I connect to WIFI when installing Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless

I am installing Ubuntu - I am quite new to this.  After I choose language I keep getting not connected to network.  How do I connect to WiFi?  I don't have a wired connection - it is a notebook with no network port.

Comment: Look for an inverted triangle kind of WiFi symbol at the top right corner of your screen. Click on it and choose your WiFi and supply the password. If this doesn't work, you may have to find an USB to Ethernet adapter.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply.  I have tried configuring but it doesn't work. I will have to try the adapter now.  Although it connects to WiFi when I boot Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing directly, use 'Try ubuntu', then try to look if there's an additional driver and use it.
When connected, install ubuntu.